# Spring vs CDI scopes

Tags: spring, scope, cdi

Which are the exact differences between the scopes of `Spring` and `CDI` ? For example: `Singleton (Spring)` and `ApplicationScoped (CDI)`

Comment: Spring also offers Application, Request and Session scope, you can find in spring-web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** they are different, but you only mentioned some of the scopes of both worlds.

**Spring** supports the following scopes:

- Singleton
- Prototype
- Application (Web)
- Session (Web)
- Request (Web)

Therefore the **Singleton** and **Prototype** scopes exist for any Spring application (managed by an `ApplicationContext`), even for a command line implementation. The scopes **Application**, **Session** and **Request** are introduced by a `spring-web` dependeny and managed by a `WebAppicationContext` in Spring.

Spring typically creates a hierarchy of two DI contexts for a web application. The root context is bound to the main application and only offers Singleton and Prototype. The Web context, which uses the root context as a parent, is bound to the servlet context and offers all scopes. Only Application scope beans are available from servlet context as attributes (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49820934/12890)).

**Jakarta EE** offers the following [build-in scopes](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-3.0.html#builtin_scopes):

- Application
- Session
- Conversion
- Request

For Jakarta CDI the support of the build-in scopes is depending on the container management. Servlet containers typically support all of the above, others may only support the Application scope which in such a case behaves similar to the Spring Singleton scope.

The scopes **Application**, **Session** and **Request** are similar in both worlds. There nothing like Conversation scope out of the box in Spring but you may implement custom scopes in both worlds and Conversation can be implemented similar to Session scope in Spring.

Comment: @BalusC I know it's about CDI, but my link to JSF (where the conversation scope originally came from as far as I know) was misleading - thanks!

Comment: @BalusC At least for Spring the scopes Application, Session and Request are introduced by the `spring-web` dependency only. For Jakarta I am not sure about the behavior for scopes other than Application outside a servlet container.

Comment: Argh, a little blindfold today